# Angular checkbox loading as ng-checked='true' on ng-change not seeing the change to false

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-scope, pug

Im having an issue with my ng-repeat checkboxes.
On modal load their status is set from the `$http.get`
They load fine. but if they are set to `true` on load when clicked on the `ng-change` dosent seem to register it but when clicked again it see the change to true. this is shown in my `pre` and `console.log()`

I'll put what code I can

### PUG

```
form.form-horizontal(name='sysInfo' ng-controller='sysInfo' ng-repeat='sysName in sysNames')
    label{{sysName.friendyName}}
        input(type='checkbox' ng-change='submit(sysName.selected, options.sysBackend, sysName.id)'  ng-model='sysName.selected' ng-checked='select.indexOf(sysName.id) != -1')
```

Angular

```
app.controller('sysInfo', sysInfo);
    function sysInfo($scope, $rootScope, $http){
    $scope.options = function(foo) {
        var config = {params :{fooName: foo}}
        $('#myModal').modal();
        $http.get('/api/boo', config)
        .then(function(resp) { 
            var selectArray = [];
            $rootScope.select = [];
            $rootScope.options = res.data.data[0];
            $rootScopesysNames = resp.data.sysInfo;
            $rootScope.sysLinks = resp.data.sysNamedLinks;
            angular.forEach(resp.data.sysNamedLinks, function(value1, key1){
                angular.forEach(resp.data.sysInfo, function(value0, key0){
                    if(value1.sysLinkId === value0.id){
                        selectArray.push(value0.id)
                        $rootScope.select = selectArray
                    }
                })
             })
        })
}
```

`res.data.data[0] = {id:1, sysBackend:'fumanchu'}`
`resp.data.sysInfo = [{id: 1, friendlyName:foo},{id: 2, friendlyName:fo},{id: 3, friendlyName:boo},]`
`resp.data.sysNamedLinks = [{sysLinkId:1},{sysLinkId:2},{sysLinkId:3}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is happening because you have some conflicts between `ng-model` and `ng-checked`.

refer the below example, the checkbox is initialized to be `checked` by `ng-checked` expression but `ng-model` value is `false`.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-init="test=false;checked=true;">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="test" ng-checked="checked === true">
  {{test}}
</div>
```

In the second example, there is no confilcts and works well.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-init="test=true;checked=true;">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="test" ng-checked="checked === true">
  {{test}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much I've made the change of
`input(type='checkbox' ng-init=''sysName.selected=select.indexOf(sysName.id) != -1; checked=true' ng-change='submit(sysName.selected, options.sysBackend, sysName.id)'  ng-model='sysName.selected' ng-checked='select.indexOf(sysName.id) != -1')`

and seems to have done the trick. Thanks for that

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-init="test=false;checked=true;">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="test" ng-checked="checked === true">
  {{test}}
</div>
```